# Двойная фильтрация

Tags: php, mysql

Всем добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить задачку которая возникла. 
Нужно что бы при выборке из бд данные фильтровались сначало по одному параметру и потом сразу же по другому тоесть например у меня есть ряд данных пренадлежащих одной категории и в этих данных есть параметр цена. Так вот мне нужно сначала отсортировать все по категориям и потом данные в этих категориях отсортировать по ценам впорядке убывания. Можно ли решить данный вопрос только с помощью SQL запроса ??

Comment: Фильтровать или всё таки сортировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY category ASC, price ASC`

суть: соритруется по полю `category`, все одинаковые категории будут отсортированы по полю `price`
Все просто :)

Comment: *price desc*

Comment: да как угодно)) не принципиально,я пример показываю, а не решение :)

Comment: Спасибо. Я почему то думал что так не работает.

Comment: не, нормально работает.